# Is there a plugin etc for Firefox that tracks network activity?

Tags: firefox, networking, flash, mythtv, reverse-engineer

I want to be able to use the ABC (Australia) [iView page](http://www.iinet.net.au/my/media/abc/index.html) on my mythtv box but without having to use a mouse. And as it's all flash based I'm trying to reverse engineer it to work out where the media content comes from and build my own menu system. So what I need is something that sniffs out the network activity while I'm looking at the videos. Then with luck I can work out how it's all sorted on their server and download the flvs directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Here is a how-to: http://www.ehow.com/how_2238085_monitor-network-activity-firebug.html for doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've found the URLs involved, if they're "rtmp://"-type URLs you'll need something like [RTMPDump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) to retrieve them. This program can grab the same video stream that a Flash player app uses.